# svn:ignore exclude a file from being ignored

Tags: svn, svnignore

I have a directory which contains files with various extensions. I would like to do the equivalent of the following .gitignore code in svn:ignore:

```
*.* # ignore everything
!.htaccess # except this file
```

How do I achieve this in svn:ignore?

Answer (score 3):

If you've already added the .htaccess file to SVN control, then it won't matter. You will always see changes to that file. The only time the ignore list comes into play is for files which have not yet been added to the repository. You can ignore everything in the directory globally and still add the .htaccess file to SVN control and see modifications, etc.

Comment: That is not true, when I do so - the .htacecss file became marked as deleted... (what is clearly what is not to be).

Comment: Just editing the svn:ignore property will never delete a file. So what did you do exactly? And what are you trying to do? You can't ignore changes in a file already added to SVN, and this question was about NOT ignoring changes to certain files anyway.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just want to say that when you set previously added directory to repository (with files) as ignored - It make these directory (and files in it) as deleted. (since it was in repository before, but now you want it ignore). In that moment is is not possible to revert (inner) file deleting - you would have to revert parent dir at first... So, short way - ignoring whole parent directory is not the way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can - [`svn:ignore`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) takes in a blacklist (files to be ignored), not a whitelist (files that are not to be ignored).

Comment: Sucks... I don't want to make a long list of allowed file extensions.

Comment: Indeed ... but with Subversion 1.8 you can set it up once on the server (see [inherited properties](http://wiki.apache.org/subversion/InheritedProperties)) and have it cascade down to your projects (instead of having to apply the same `svn:ignore` pattern to every project folder).

Comment: Not a solution, there are folders in which those extensions are not to be ignored (for example, 1 folder with uploaded images - ignored -, another with GUI images - obviously not ignored).

Comment: You could try using a [pre-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html) to fail a commit if it contains extensions which don't match your pre-defined whitelist

Comment: I just want to hide all files (except .htaccess) from `svn status/svn commit` in certain directories. They are uploaded files, not committed.