# is it possible for subversion to ignore all directory contents except one file?

Tags: svn, ignore

I have a /packages directory with one file in it that I want to commit and watch.  However, if new things are added, I'd like to ignore them.  Is that possible?

Comment: Unfortunately not - see [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056183/svnignore-exclude-a-file-from-being-ignored/18073837#18073837).

Comment: Right, I was wondering if I could do something like `svn:ignore ./packages/*` after the one file was committed.

Comment: That would work, but might be confusing later on. Also - the `svn:ignore` property should be placed on the `packages/` folder, with the value `*` or `*.*`

Comment: why would it be confusing?

Comment: For argument's sake, let's say you committed the file then added the svn:ignore property and committed that. Then, you modify the committed file. The SVN client might think the committed file should be ignored, so when you try to commit again, it reports that there is nothing to commit. This has happened on TortoiseSVN one or two times but then it realizes its mistake and shows the modified file ready to be committed.

Comment: I have to disagree with Sameer--using the *.* ignore pattern is precisely the way to do it, as @Ben has accurately described in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

If a file matches the ignore pattern, nothing prevents you from manually adding that file to SVN. Then SVN will track that file as normal, you can commit changes and see modifications without difficulty. The only thing the ignore list affects, is new files that are not under revision control.

Comment: +1: Among the comments posted on the question and the other answers, this is the most straightforward approach--and quite accurate. Though there's really no need to read further, [Part 2](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/tortoisesvn-and-subversion-cookbook-part-2-file-operations-and-subversion-filtering/) of my [TortoiseSVN Cookbook](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/tortoisesvn-and-subversion-cookbook-part-11-subversion-and-oracle/) describes this same information (albeit a lot less concisely :-).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using pre-commit hook feature. You can ignore all the file names other than that file to get committed.
See this link for more information http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.svn-pre-commit.php

Answer (score 0):

You could always try using the changelists feature - place all the other files on your ignore-on-commit changelist and they won't bother you again. This might not be quite what you want though.

You can however exclude files using the sparse directory feature, setting the depth to "exclude". This works with individual files (well, it does using TortoiseSVN and the 'make depth sticky' option - the file will disappear from your working copy, not coming back if you update, unless you reset the directory depth)

Be careful to set the depth on the files, not the directory. Any files subsequently added will appear in your directory and you'll have to exclude them too. It's probably possible to set the directory to exclude everything and then re-include just the 1 file you want - I haven't tried that, let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom hook which will work only on that file. You may code that as a batch file or a perl file. Put the file in your subversion custom hooks folder or hooks folder and the code may be running on post commit that you get notified only for that file not the others in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Tortoise git and i have ignored the packages via. `.gitignore` file as below. If I make changes in `repositories.config` file, the changes window shows it:

```
# Visual Studio Nuget package directory
packages/*/
```

Comment: Was asking about svn not git.